# Change data roll over to number of days

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, data-monitoring

My data rolls over every 28 days. The data tracker on my Samsung Galaxy S6 is only rolling over on the same date each month. This is frustrating. I want to know how to change the data roll over to every 28 days instead of the same date each month.

Comment: The last answer there works on stock Marshmallow for me. If that doesn't help you, add this piece of information to your question by editing it

Comment: It's not *quite* a duplicate, because this is about making the cycle fixed-length instead of changing which date, but the same procedure on the other answer should work for this too - just choose the right option in the data cycle dialog. If it doesn't work for whatever reason, complain back here and your question can be reopened.